# How can I decrypt a column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, hash, passwords

I have a column for storing passwords in a SQL Server database table, where all the data is encrypted like this:

```
PzevsnVFZS36DfoHVAkP04xGvtnuzEtJ3gnnGbzlLxw=
```

How can I decrypt my column because I don't know key and type of hashing

Comment: SQL server encrypts data as a varbinary, that isn't a varbinary. Firstly, I'd guess that that's been done using a salt, and likely SHA or RSA. Secondly, however, it's encrypted for a reason; if you don't know the key or hash, it's because you shoulnd't... Encryption is **designed** so that you can't decrypt it without the right passwords, keys, hashes, etc.

Comment: If it's a **hash** - then you **cannot** "decrypt" it - by design, you **cannot** invert a hash - one hashed your data remains hashed and cannot be converted back to its original

Comment: @marc_s so what can i do

Comment: Without knowing anything about how the value was generated? Nothing.